# what is the use of kafka partition other than increasing efficiency through parallelism?

Tags: logging, bigdata, apache-kafka, flume-ng

I am using kafka for collection of logs, Is there any other advantage of partition, like can we use it later for simplify processing of our logs, if we use partition in a topic,

Partition increases parallelism, that is one advantage of using partition in kafka topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to have partitions for topic to get better efficiency and also distributing data on multiple disks and nodes.

I don't think so creating multiple partitions for a topic will be issue for your processing because KAFKA is responsible for handling inner logic of having multiple partition you just need to have topic information.
Having multiple partition will increase your throughput and decrease the latency as well.